# How to debug Flask with PyCharm?

Tags: flask, debugging, pycharm

I start Flask and it works fine. It shows me `* Debugger is active!` in the console. But when I start it in debug mode, it ends up with an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '..\\Scripts\\flask.exe'
```

How do I use the debugger with Flask?